# namespace in clojure not evaluating. Error: Unable to resolve symbol: deftest in this context, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:1:1)

Tags: emacs, clojure

Dumb newbie question here. I created a brand new lein project and I am trying to run the sample test in the "core_test.clj" file. I am using emacs and "nrepl-jack-in". But when I run "(run-all-tests)" from the repl, I get:

> Unable to resolve symbol: deftest in this context, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:1:1)

Interestingly, the test works from these two scenarios:
1) "lein test" from the commandline
- or -
2) If I put the following line in the repl beforehand:

> (ns my-prog.core-test
>     (:require [clojure.test :refer :all]
>               [my-prog.core :refer :all]))

Interestingly, this line is in the "core_test.clj" file itself, but I guess it's not evaluating for some reason. I am evaluating the buffer using Ctrl-x Ctrl-e in emacs but it does not seem to read the namespace specs.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use <kbd>C-c C-k</kbd> to evaluate your whole buffer. It loads the file in one go. Alternatively, you can `require` the namespace you need at the REPL, possibly passing in `:reload` or `:reload-all` to cause previously loaded namespaces to be loaded again. (You can also `require` your namespace at first giving it an alias -- `(require '[foo.core :as foo])` -- then use the chord to reload.)

<kbd>C-x C-e</kbd> is only really useful for evaluating single expressions for their values. The nice thing about it is that those expressions need not live at top level. (For example, you might put a `(comment ...)` section with some useful test expressions in your file, then use <kbd>C-x C-e</kbd> to check their values given the current state of the JVM.)

Comment: C-c C-k does not load the namespace in the file. I have to manually put the namespace in the repl still. I am at a loss why it would load the test, but not the namespace

Comment: Just to make sure we're on the same page: `C-c C-k` should cause the namespace to be loaded (as if by `require :reload`), but it should not cause the REPL to switch to it. If the loading doesn't happen, you should try restarting your JVM process. If you want to switch the REPL namespace, you can say `(in-ns 'foo.core)` after loading the namespace with `C-c C-k` or `require`, or you could use the `C-c M-n` binding providing by nrepl.el (sets REPL namespace to that of the current buffer). There might be a binding which does both, not sure... I hardly ever switch away from the `user` namespace.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you've solved this or not, but I ran into this issue recently when upgrading an old library that had Clojure 1.2 as a dependency. After a little bit of time, I realized the `:refer :all` syntax was [added in Clojure 1.4](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/98367ceffe9c85dd6cad96a046c51e7f9aefa9f2/changes.md). There are two solutions to this issue:

- Upgrade to Clojure 1.4+:

  > In the `project.clj` update the dependency, e.g. `[org.clojure/clojure "1.4.0"]` to switch to Clojure 1.4.
- Use `use` instead; in this case the namespace declaration would be:

  ```
  (ns my-prog.core-test 
    (:use [[clojure.test] 
           [my-prog.core]))
  ```

Hope that helps!